# Where did I go wrong with my javascript handling my slideshow image banner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I have so far, it's a very basic slide image banner inside my header tag in html. Basically, every 3 seconds, I have a new image showing up. I plan on using that for the mock exercise I'm working on right now but unfortunately, something went wrong in Javascript. At least, that's what I think it is. The image banner does NOT keep going through the images. It just sticks to one picture and goes no where else. No other pictures show up. This is the error I'm getting inside my console log right now.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null. at changeImage (slideshow.js:7)
```

Here's the HTML I have right now.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kenneth's Slide Show Demonstration</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='slideshow.css'>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wallpaper"><img src="ferrari-logo0.jpg" id="ferrari" alt="ferrari logo"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

now for CSS.

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wallpaper {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-bottom:dashed black 1px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#ferrari {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    height:250px;
    width:400px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#wallpaper:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

And then here's the Javascript I've made.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('ferrari');
var imageArray=['ferrari-logo0.jpg', 'ferrari-logo1.jpg', 'Ferrari-logo2', 'ferrari-logo3.jpg'];

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
};

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage(),4000);

function changeImage();
```

Where did I go wrong? If I can make a special request, I'd like straight Vanilla javascript. I know Jquery is popular but I'm not currently studying that right now.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: *Where did I go wrong* Can you elaborate? Surely you don't expect us to look at all this code and try to figure out what (if anything) is wrong. Give a specific example of an issue. Check your browser's console to see if any errors are present

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording, what I mean is that the image remains stagnant. The first image shows up but just sticks and the banner doesn't keep rotating through the image array.

Answer (score 1):

No need in round brackets in setInterval for function changeImage();

```
var imageArray = ['ferrari-logo0.jpg', 'ferrari-logo1.jpg', 'Ferrari-logo2', 'ferrari-logo3.jpg'];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById('ferrari');
    if (myImage) {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
    }
};

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 4000);
```

Try it. You must pass a function, not invoke it.

Comment: here's the error I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Try to put var myImage = document.getElementById('ferrari'); inside changeImage() function. Where you invoke your script? I mean add as <script>your code</script> or load as <script src="myscripts.js"></script>

Comment: This error maybe, cause your html doesn't load, when the script executes. That's why myImage is null

Comment: oh and I added another function on top of that. window.onload = function() {
changeThisShit();
};

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your JavaScript in the head of your page, so when your JS runs, the `ferrari` element does not exist yet. `getElementById` returns `null` if it doesn't find an element with the `id` you provide. Thus, you are in effect trying to do `null.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);`. Since `null` doesn't have a `setAttribute` method you are getting the error message telling you `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`.

Moving your script tag below the `ferrari` element should fix it. It has become a best practice to [load your JS as low in the page as you can](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) for other performance related reasons. You could also keep your script tag where it is if you wrap your code in a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoke changeImage, like this `setInterval(changeImage,4000)` also `changeImage()` is already defined, you just need to call it.

Here is a working example.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var myImage = document.getElementById('ferrari');
var imageArray=['http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1', 
    'http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2', 
    'http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3', 
    'http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4'
      ];

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 4000);

changeImage(); 
 

});
```

```css
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wallpaper {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-bottom:dashed black 1px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#ferrari {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    height:250px;
    width:400px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#wallpaper:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Wallpapers</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wallpaper">
 <img src="" id="ferrari" alt="ferrari logo"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's best practice to load your scripts after html is loaded, so place your html before then end body tag `</body>`, or use `DOMContentLoaded` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded